# Cannot make release of UWP App, because of error ILT1307

Tags: uwp, .net-core, release

When trying to make a release for UWP app I get this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ILT1307: Assemblies 
'D:\Project_26_05_2018\Project\Project\Project.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\Windows.winmd' and 
'D:\Project_26_05_2018\Project\Project\Project.UWP\obj\x86\Release\ilc\in\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd' 
have conflicting simple names.  Project.UWP
```

I am using `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform V 6.1.5`

Option `Compile with .Net native tool chain` is checked,

I am trying to create a package only x86 and it do not work!

Comment: I found some text in your error message that means there are replicate projects in your device, You could remove one of them.

Comment: I copied wrong the error, I just edited, deleting "Release" folder or "bin" folder do not help.

Comment: Have you tested with blank app?

Comment: It works with a blank app, It also works in my project if I disable the option
"Compile with .Net native tool chain", but I can not upload to the Microsoft Store without this option, it fail the validation tests.

Comment: Please try lower `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` to  version 6.0.2

Comment: Didnt worked with version 6.0.2 :-(

Comment: Could share me with a code sample that could reproduce this issue ?

Comment: Yes, I can, give me an email adress and I can send you a project sample with the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176853/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-ledmachine).